# Binding properties not working

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml

Well the title may not help to much, but here is my problem. I have problems binding properties between controls in SILVERLIGHT. Here is the structure:

1. There is a control called "ProjectItemList", this control will recieve a string and display it in a very simple way.
2. There is a control called "ProjectList", this control will recive an array of string and use the control "ProjectItemList" to represent each of the strings in the array.
3. There is a window called "ProjectWindow", this window contains a "ProjectList" control, and a dependency property called "Nombres".

The context: The "ProjectWindow" window include a "ProjectList" control, there is a binding between ProjectWindow's dependency property "Nombres" and a dependency property "ListOfNames", here is the code of the "ListOfNames" dependency property:

```
public static DependencyProperty ListOfNamesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ListOfNames", typeof(string[]), typeof(ProjectList), new PropertyMetadata(null));
public string[] ListOfNames
{
   get
   {
      return (string[])GetValue(ListOfNamesProperty);
   }

   set
   {
      SetValue(ListOfNamesProperty, value);
      List<ProjectItemList> auxList = new List<ProjectItemList>();
      foreach (string s in value)
      {
         ProjectItemList il = new ProjectItemList();
         il.Nombre = s;
         this.lb_projects.Items.Add(il);
      }
    }
 }
```

The problem is that, although the list control in "ProjectList" represent the "Nombres" property, the "Set" of "ListOfNames" is never called, so I can't create each of the "ProjectItemList" objects and represent the data.

I'm fairly new into XAML and Silverlight, so i may not considering something simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a callback to monitor property changes:

```
public static DependencyProperty ListOfNamesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ListOfNames", typeof(string[]), typeof(ProjectList),
    new PropertyMetadata(ListOfNamesChaned));

private static void ListOfNamesChaned(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    List<ProjectItemList> auxList = new List<ProjectItemList>();
    foreach (string s in value)
    {
        ProjectItemList il = new ProjectItemList();
        il.Nombre = s;
        this.lb_projects.Items.Add(il);
    }
}

public string[] ListOfNames
{
    get
    {
        return (string[])GetValue(ListOfNamesProperty);
    }

    set
    {
        SetValue(ListOfNamesProperty, value);
    }
}
```

See **Chen Kinnrot**'s answer to know why.

Answer (score 1):

When you use dependency properties, the set and get are not called through ui binding, this is your problem. 
WPF ui controls tald directrly with the dependeny property without going through your getter and setter.

Comment: It's not an error, you just need to bind to the changes, and do your logic, you can use the coerce value interception point or the property changed handler via the metadata

Answer (score 0):

For this to achieve, Raise Property Change event can be used i.e with  the propertychanged event handler,Code snippet is like:

```
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

use OnPropertyChanged to bind the property and if any change in that property.it will notify and your binding properties automatically will be changed and ui will be updated which are bound to these properties.